# Connecting FDA API to SAP Data Warehouse Cloud

Tags: openfda

I am trying to connect the Adverse Events API to SAP's Data Warehouse Cloud. I do not know what to enter in the fields, can I please get some advice?

**FDA Base URL**: https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json

1. What type of pagination? Offset or Cursor?
2. Authentication Type = Basic? Custom?

[image: SAP Integration Suite]

3. Must I add any configurations or parameters? I would like to see all of the Device Adverse Events and load them into SAP Data Warehouse Cloud.

[image: SAP Configurations]

[image: SAP Parameters]

Any help is appreciated, I do not know where to start consuming this data!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with a [bulk download](https://open.fda.gov/data/downloads/). After that you can use the [date rage filter](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=receivedate:%5B20040101%20TO%2020081231%5D&limit=1). I don't believe that a API supports an offset.